# Ruby on Rails: I installed the native pg gem on Mac OS Snow Leopard 10.6.3, but I still get an error "no such file to load -- pg"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, rubygems

I'm using Rails 3.0.1. I installed the native pg gem for postgresql with this command:

> $ export ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386'
>   $ sudo gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin/pg_config

When I run the gem list, I can see that pg 0.9 is installed.

However when I set the postgres database adaptor and re-run the server, I get this error:

> no such file to load -- pg

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file named "Gemfile" in the root of your project and add:

```
gem 'pg'
```

somewhere in the middle of it (mine is after the line "gem 'rails', '3.0.0'").

Another way to "fix" it is to create a new project with:

```
rails new <project_name> -d postgresql
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've spent an entire week looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 0.14 and the postgres.app server from heroku.  Found that my pg_config file was in the postgres.app directory tree...used that in my config and the pg gem finally installed.